# Clear all commits in GIT?

Tags: git, commit

I created a new git repo on our server and then committed all files. Once those files were committed I then created a new .gitignore file and committed it.

I did the two commits in the wrong order because the original commit added around 30k files and the .gitignore file isn't having any affect. If I could clear both commits and then commit the .gitignore file first hopefully it will dramatically reduce the volume of files and make the repo smaller.

Is this possible? I have never pushed the repo to BeanstalkApp (our hosted git account) so hopefully it is possible.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really just created the repo then I'd recommend you just recreate it -- it's possible to remove files entirely from the revision history in git but in my experience it's quite slow.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about recreating it? Delete the git folder and run 'git init' again?

Comment: Yes, just remove (or, more safely, move elsewhere) the .git folder then re-run git init

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a new commit which removes the unwanted files. From that point on, they will be ignored as per the .gitignore file.

Or, you can try `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and simply delete the initial commit.

Comment: But this won't remove the files from the revision history; as such, they'll still be downloaded when users clone the repo.  For 30k files that aren't needed this can be a problem.

Comment: I'd expect the second option, where you interactively delete the commit, to remove the files from the revision history. The dangling commit will be garbage collected when you do a 'git gc' and hence won't take up any space or bandwidth from that point on. Is that not how it works?

Comment: So run 'git rebase -i HEAD~2' followed by 'git gc'?

Comment: @dannymcc: Yes, and when the editor opens with the list of commits, delete the line containing the commit you want to remove. Since you've only just created the repository, Peter Zion's answer is probably easier, though.

Comment: Don't forget that you can't delete the initial commit that way.